# Encoding videos for use with Adobe Live Streaming

Tags: adobe, ffmpeg, video-streaming, video-encoding

I have an original video coded at 20Mbps, 1920x1080, 30fps and want to convert it down to be 640x480 30fps at a range of (3 different) bitrates for use by Adobe Live Streaming.

Should I use ffmpeg to resize and encode at the 3 bitrates then use f4fpackager to create the f4m f4f and f4x files or just use ffmpeg to reduce the resolution and then f4fpackager to encode the relevant bitrates?

I've had several tries so far, but when encoded the videos seem to play at a much larger bitrate than they've been encoded at. For example, if I set up the OSMF to play from my webserver, I'd be expecting my best encoded video to play at 1,500kbps but it's way above that.

Has anyone had any experience of encoding for use like this?

I'm using the following options to f4fpackager

```
--bitrate=1428 --segment-duration 30 --fragment-duration 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

f4fpackager doesn't do any encoding, it does 2 things:
- fragment the mp4 files (mp4 -> f4f)
- generate a Manifest (f4m) file referencing all you fragmented files (f4f)

So the process is:
- transcode your source file in all the size/bitrate that you want to provide (eg: 1920x01080@4Mbps, 1280x720@2Mbps, etc)
- use f4fpackager to convert the mp4 to f4f (this is the fragmentation step)
- use f4fpackager to generate the Manifest.f4m referencing the files that you generated in the previous step

the --bitrate option of f4fpackager should match the value that you use with ffmpeg, this parameter is used to generate the manifest file with the correct bitrate value of each quality